# Donut Tutorial Coffee Cup has holes in it

Tags: edit-mode

I have another question about this donut tutorial. I just finished modeling the coffee cup, but it has holes in it where the handle meets the cup. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without being able to see the specific modifiers you have on your mesh, it's hard to say for sure. I'm guessing you made a cup shaped model with a solidify modifier to give it thickness. If that's the case, you can just apply the modifier, then go into edit mode and patch those holes. If that's not it, we really need to see a screenshot which shows the actual mesh topology and the modifiers applied to it. You can also upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ if you want more specific advice.

Comment: @Rekov: I just added a new picture that shows the modifiers on the side. The solidify modifier was applied previously. I'll be uploading the .blend file shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you just have some extra geometry in there that you definitely don't need. You can select contiguous bits of mesh by hovering over them with the cursor and hitting <kbd>L</kbd>. Delete the excess:

[image]

Next you need to delete the interior faces of the handle. I've temporarily disabled the subdivision modifier here so I can better see what I'm doing:

[image]

In face select mode, I first hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> (to select loop) and click to select one face loop, then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> (to select loop and keep previous selection) to select the other, and delete these faces.

I used <kbd>L</kbd> to select the now disconnected geometry that comprised the inside of the handle, and deleted that too.

In Edge select mode, I hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> to select the edge loops surrounding the now open holes in the mesh, and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill them. The last step is removing the creases and reenabling the subdivision surface.